# Where are the snapshots of a db in Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

So far, I could see my auto-created snapshots from the PG Backup and the manually created, under the Postgres - > Databases -> Snapshots.

Now, instead of my snapshots, I only see this message:

`Snapshots are archives of an entire database stored in a single file. Snapshots can be used to create an archive of the history of your database for compliance or reference.`

Where have they gone?

Comment: Does running 'heroku pg:backups list' show any?

Comment: I have the same problem... did anyone report this to Heroku yet?

Comment: Yes CraigKerstiens, the 'heroku pgbackups' lists my backups. But on Heroku page, I cannot see/create/delete anything.

Comment: Yes Cristian, it happens to all my apps and already sent a ticket to heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the ticket I sent to heroku, they fixed it in few hours! Obviously, by mistake they disappeared.